# page heading doesn't show up

Tags: joomla-3.x

when i turn on the "Page Heading" in "Page Display" tab, nothing shows up.

[image]

I'm using a costume template (sj market).

I think the code part that is suppose to show the Page Heading, is missing somewhere.
How can i fix this?

Comment: anyone?? I'm looking forward to your help

Answer (score 1):

I added this code part to default.php in templates\sj_market\html\com_virtuemart\category

```
<?php
   //page heading goes here - if it's turned on
   $menu = &JSite::getMenu();
   $active = $menu->getActive();
   $menuname = $active->params->get('page_heading');
   if($active->params->get('show_page_heading', 1)==1){      
      echo "<h1>".$menuname."</h1>";
   }
?>
```

problem solved in virtuemart pages.

but still i dont know what to do about home page. 
there is only h3 in home page...

Answer (score 1):

I helped you and I do not think you tried my method. As stated in the other post.

Use your editor and select the text and for styling use h1. It bypasses any template glitches and is better for SEO. Still fill out the the Browser Page title but set to show page heading NO.